# Error in Java Import statement "The import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull and NotEmpty cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, validation, pom.xml

I am new to Java and Spring Framework. After developing Spring boot project, I found the following errors in class :

**Cannot resolve symbol 'validation'**

This is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Can someone guide me on what I am doing and how it can be rectified?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi buddy, Could you be please clear  - where are  you seeing the error exactly?  Is it in pom.xml or it is showing error on a class when you build the project? Please add screen shot if possible. Community can help you better.

Comment: The error showed in a class. The below code works for me. I added this dependency in pom.xml and now it's solved.

<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>

Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please add below dependency in pom.xml under  tag and try again.

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: This code works for me.

Thank you!